# How do I bind to sample data in a string?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I want to bind a string to sample data.  I could bind to code-behind, but then it flashes on the phone's screen until the sample data disappears.  I know how to bind to lists and view that in simulated previews, I don't know the syntax for creating a string in sample data.

Below is the sample data I have.  I would like to add an attribute to the variable called stringVar.  It is just a string.

```
<local:ListPage
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"       
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListPage" >

    <local:ListPage.stringVar />
    <local:ListPage.ItemList>
        <local:Book id="0" title="item 1"/>
    </local:ListPage.ItemList>
</local:ListPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a resource in your xaml

```
<local:ListPage
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"       
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListPage" >
    <local:ListPage.Resources>
        <sys:String x:Key="MyStaticString">Hello world!<sys:String>
    </local:ListPage.Resources>

    <local:ListPage.stringVar />
    <local:ListPage.ItemList>
        <local:Book id="0" title="{StaticResource MyStaticString}"/>
    </local:ListPage.ItemList>
</local:ListPage>
```